# Oracle bug when using JSON_ARRAYAGG with CASE expression to emulate standard SQL FILTER

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I'm using Oracle 18c (reproduces in 19c as well) and I'd like to emulate the standard SQL `FILTER` clause in the `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregate function to filter out values from the aggregation. However, this produces an error:

```sql
select json_arrayagg(
  case when t.a < 2 then json_object(key 'a' value t.a) end
)
from (
  select 1 a
  from dual
  union all
  select 2 a
  from dual
) t
```

The error being:

> ORA-40590: invalid format

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=286f5a541a3733ed0dcf61cc8905b6db). What's causing the error? Is it a bug in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem to be a bug, [which has been fixed already in 19.10](https://twitter.com/connor_mc_d/status/1409844145850503174). Adding an explicit `ELSE` clause seems to resolve the issue:

```sql
select json_arrayagg(
  case 
    when t.a < 2 then json_object(key 'a' value t.a) 
    else null
  end
)
from (
  select 1 a
  from dual
  union all
  select 2 a
  from dual
) t
```

This now produces the expected result:

```
[{"a":1}]
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0804a01906a5a70e437f408d1a09211b).